# Asp.net core got 401 Bearer error="invalid_token" when deploy on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, xmlhttprequest

I've been using [QuickApp](https://github.com/emonney/QuickApp), a template using ASP.Net Core with Angular to start a new project, and it has worked perfectly in development mode.

And I try to deploy on local IIS, it went well until logged in, keep logging 401 when the app try to call API:
[image]

request & response headers:
[image]

Then I've been doing some surveys and checked Event Viewer:
[image]

I found out the authorization token in header seems not changing in development environment,
but keep changing when I deploy on IIS.

I'm not sure what happened, not even know how to ask properly...
I guess maybe something about IdentifyServer4's configuration?

if need more information, please tell me where to fetch it.